# Are std::condition_variable wait predicates thread-safe?

Tags: c++, condition-variable

Take this code:

```
std::condition_variable var;
var.wait(lock, [&sharedBool] { return sharedBool; });
```

When `var` reads from sharedBool, is that thread safe? If it isn't, is making `sharedBool` a `std::atomic<bool>` reasonable?

Comment: You should use `{ std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{your_mutex}; sharedBool = newvalue; var.notify_all(); }` (or notify_one) to update your bool and trigger an evaluation of the predicate. An extra synchronization primitive will only complicate things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from `sharedBool` happens under the protection of the mutex locked by `lock`.

As long as all concurrent accessed to `sharedBool` happen while a lock to the same mutex is held, your program is thread-safe.

Since you also cannot `wait` on a condition variable *without* holding a lock, it is usually not reasonable to use an atomic for this use case.

Comment: Doesn't wait unlock the unique_lock, and only lock it when wait exits?

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard Yes, but it re-locks before invoking the predicate. Everything inside the lambda body is only executed while the lock is held.

Comment: I see, thanks. How did you know about it locking before checking the predicate, as I can't find anything on cppreference about that.

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard Do you understand what an atomic "unlock and wait" operation is and how that's the whole point of a condition variable?

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard Look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait): *Note that `lock` must be acquired before entering this method, and it is reacquired after `wait(lock)` exits, which means that  `lock` can be used to guard access to `stop_waiting()`.*

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard You're very welcome. These things can be subtle, so it's better to ask than make assumptions and get it wrong.

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard I ought to note that using atomics inside the condition variable's wait frequently leads to misuse and invalidating requirements of the condition variable, leading to problems like occasional infinite waits.